# I am getting "Can't retrieve entity config: productcustomizer/productsetting" error when save product

Tags: php, magento

I have created custom tab, I want to save data in database when click on save button in edit product page in magento admin then i am getting "**Can't retrieve entity config: productcustomizer/productsetting**" error

**config.xml** file

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer>
            <version>1.0.0</version>
        </ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <helpers>
            <productcustomizer>
                <class>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Helper</class>
            </productcustomizer>
        </helpers>
        <models>
            <productcustomizer>
                <class>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model</class>
                <resourceModel>productcustomizer_mysql4</resourceModel>
            </productcustomizer>
            <productcustomizer_mysql4>
                <class>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Mysql4</class>
                <entities>
                    <cliparts>
                        <table>productcustomizer_cliparts</table>
                    </cliparts>
                    <backgrounds>
                        <table>productcustomizer_backgrounds</table>
                    </backgrounds>
                    <fonts>
                        <table>productcustomizer_fonts</table>
                    </fonts>
                    <productsetting>
                        <table>productcustomizer_setings</table>
                    </productsetting>
                </entities>
            </productcustomizer_mysql4>
        </models>
        <resources>
            <productcustomizer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer</module>
                    <class>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Resource_Eav_Mysql4_Setup</class>
                </setup>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </productcustomizer_setup>
            <productcustomizer_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
            </productcustomizer_write>
            <productcustomizer_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </productcustomizer_read>
        </resources>
        <blocks>
            <productcustomizer>
                <class>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Block</class>
            </productcustomizer>
            <adminhtml>
                <rewrite>
                    <catalog_product_edit_tabs>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Block_Adminhtml_Tabs</catalog_product_edit_tabs>
                </rewrite>
            </adminhtml>
        </blocks>
    </global>
    <frontend>      
        <routers>
          <productcustomizer>
              <use>standard</use>
              <args>
                 <module>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer</module>
                 <frontName>productcustomizer</frontName>
              </args>
           </productcustomizer>
        </routers>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productcustomizer>
                    <file>productcustomizer.xml</file>
                </productcustomizer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
    </frontend> 
    <admin>
        <routers>
            <productcustomizer>
                <use>admin</use>
                <args>
                    <module>ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer</module>
                    <frontName>admin_productcustomizer</frontName>
                </args>
            </productcustomizer>
        </routers>
    </admin>
    <adminhtml>
        <menu>
            <productcustomizer module="productcustomizer">
                <title>Product Customizer</title>
                <sort_order>100</sort_order>
                <children>
                    <productcustomizercliparts module="productcustomizer">
                        <title>Clip arts</title>
                        <sort_order>0</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_productcustomizer/adminhtml_productcustomizercliparts</action>
                    </productcustomizercliparts>
                </children>
                <!-- <children>
                    <productcustomizerbackgrounds module="productcustomizer">
                        <title>Backgrounds</title>
                        <sort_order>1</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_productcustomizer/adminhtml_productcustomizerbackgrounds</action>
                    </productcustomizerbackgrounds>
                </children> -->
                <children>
                    <productcustomizerfonts module="productcustomizer">
                        <title>Fonts</title>
                        <sort_order>2</sort_order>
                        <action>admin_productcustomizer/adminhtml_productcustomizerfonts</action>
                    </productcustomizerfonts>
                </children>
            </productcustomizer>
        </menu>
        <acl>
            <resources>
                <all>
                    <title>Allow Everything</title>
                </all>
                <admin>
                    <children>
                        <productcustomizer module="productcustomizer" translate="title">
                            <title>Product Customizer</title>
                            <sort_order>1000</sort_order>
                            <children>
                                <productcustomizerbackend translate="title">
                                    <title>Product Customizer Setting</title>
                                </productcustomizerbackend>
                            </children>
                        </productcustomizer>
                    </children>
                </admin>
            </resources>
        </acl>
        <layout>
            <updates>
                <productcustomizer>
                    <file>productcustomizer.xml</file>
                </productcustomizer>
            </updates>
        </layout>
        <events>
            <catalog_product_save_after>
                <observers>
                    <productcustomizer>
                        <type>singleton</type>
                        <class>productcustomizer/observer</class>
                        <method>saveProductTabData</method>
                    </productcustomizer>
                </observers>
            </catalog_product_save_after>
        </events>
    </adminhtml>
</config>
```

I have created "**ProductCustomizer/ProductCustomizer/Model/Observer.php**"

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomize_Model_Observer
{

    public function saveProductTabData(Varien_Event_Observer $observer)
    {             
        //$product = $observer->getEvent()->getProduct();
        $product = $observer->getProduct();

        Mage::log($product->getID());
        try {
            $product = $this->getProduct();
            $productId = $product->getId();

            $data = $this->_getRequest()->getPost();

            $customize_price = $data['customize_price'];
            $customize_data = $data['customize_data'];
            $customize_status = $data['customize_status'];

            Mage::log($data);

            $checkProduct = Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/productsetting')->loadByProductId($productId);
            if($checkProduct->getProductId() == ''){                
                $productModel = Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/productsetting');
                $productModel->setProductId($productId);
                $productModel->setCustomizePrice($customize_price);
                $productModel->setCustomizeData($customize_data);
                $productModel->setCustomizeStatus($customize_status);
                $productModel->save();
            } else {
                $checkProduct = Mage::getModel('productcustomizer/productsetting')->loadByProductId($productId);
                $checkProduct->setImprintWidth($imprint_width);
                $checkProduct->setImprintHeight($imprint_height);
                $checkProduct->save();
            }

            /**
             * Uncomment the line below to save the product
             *
             */
            //$product->save();
        }
        catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
        }
    }

    /**
     * Retrieve the product model
     *
     * @return Mage_Catalog_Model_Product $product
     */
    public function getProduct()
    {
        return Mage::registry('product');
    }

    /**
     * Shortcut to getRequest
     *
     */
    protected function _getRequest()
    {
        return Mage::app()->getRequest();
    }
}
```

I have cleared cache and Enabled logs but nothing logs in "system.log" file.

**ProductCustomizer/ProductCustomizer/Model/Productsetting.php** file

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Productsetting extends Mage_Core_Model_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('productcustomizer/productsetting');
    }

    public function loadByProductId($productid)
    {
        $data= $this->_getResource()->loadByProductId($productid);
        $this->setData($data);
        return $this;
    }
}
```

**ProductCustomizer/ProductCustomizer/Model/Mysql4/Productsetting.php**

```
<?php
    class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Mysql4_Productsetting extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Abstract
    {
        public function _construct()
        {    
            // Note that the magentorex_id refers to the key field in your database table.
            $this->_init('productcustomizer/productsetting', 'id');
        }

        public function loadByProductId($productid)
        {
            $adapter = $this->_getReadAdapter();



            $select = $adapter->select()
                ->from($this->getTable('productcustomizer/productsetting'), '*')
                ->where('product_id = :product_id');

            $bind = array(':product_id' => (string)$productid);

            return $adapter->fetchRow($select, $bind);
        }
    }
```

**ProductCustomizer/ProductCustomizer/Model/Mysql4\Productsetting/Collection.php**

```
<?php
class ProductCustomizer_ProductCustomizer_Model_Mysql4_Productsetting_Collection extends Mage_Core_Model_Mysql4_Collection_Abstract
{
    public function _construct()
    {
        parent::_construct();
        $this->_init('productcustomizer/productsetting');
    }
}
```